# On the Hurwitz stability of quasipolynomials

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, transcendental-equations

Suppose that $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider the transcendental polynomial
$$
p\lambda^2+p\lambda-a\left(e^{p\lambda}-1\right)e^{-q\lambda}=0,\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
I would like some suggestions on beautiful and clean techniques for establishing conditions on $p,q$, and $a$ to guarantee that $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)<0$ for this transcendental polynomial. Now, I'm familiar with the work of Pontryagin (he generalized the Hermite-Biehler theorem to so-called quasipolynomials) and others in this direction. I've even seen some people use basic ideas from the theory of complex variables (e.g. Rouche's theorem, etc) to attack this kind of problem. I'm fishing for ideas on something elegant, and rigorous. I'm open to literature suggestions as well.

Comment: Are you looking to ensure $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda) < 0$ for every $\lambda$ that satisfies the equation? If so, $\lambda = 0$ is always a solution and does not satisfy $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda) < 0$.

Comment: I'm looking for conditions on $p,q$, and $a$ so that all the roots $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ of the equation lie in the left half-plane of the complex plane. Your observation is very interesting.